# How can I use “vbs”—or “Batch processing”—to start a service?

Tags: batch, vbscript

1. I want to use vbs or batch processing to start my service with my administrator password.
2. I learning some code from internet,but I can't running it.
3. My perpose :Normal user must input the administrator password evey time to starting the system service. I want build a vbs or batch processing code to instead inputing every time.(In my local machine ,I'm the adminstrator)
4. The service is exist my locale machine.just starting it menual.
5. OS:windows server 2016

```
Option explicit
Dim oShell
set oShell= Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.Run "RunAs /noprofile /user:administrator ""cmd /k"""
WScript.Sleep 100
oShell.Sendkeys "my password"
'can't run here in administrator cmd windows.
oShell.Sendkeys "{ENTER} sc start ""my service name"""
'net start "my service name" 
Set oShell = Nothing
Wscript.Quit
```

> 1. what's wrong in my AUTOIT code,the script is running ,but the service is not starting.
> 2. I learn the autoit code from here ,[spiceworks](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/632406-run-a-simple-script-but-as-the-local-admin)

```
Local $sUsername = "Administrator"
Local $sPassword = "mypassword"
Local $sDomain   = "WIN-7SK878BII9M" & "\"
Local $service = "DS License Server"

local $sCommand1 = @comspec & " /c " & "sc start " & $service

Local $iPID = RunAs($sUserName, $sDomain, $sPassword, 0,$sCommand1 , "", @SW_HIDE);RunAsWait->RunAs
```

Comment: Technically speaking, you are not using VBScript to start a service, but cmd. To really use vbscript, see this: http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/vbscript/wmi_services.htm

Comment: are you aware that runas has the option /savecred that lets you store your username and password for a given runas command? This would not only be a little bit safer than having the credentials in some script file but also you bypass the need to use gui automation on windows prompts

Comment: look at `net start` (requires admin access)